# How to improve page loaging speed of laravel project on mobile

Tags: laravel

I have laravel project. The url is www.el-7l.com.
I have tested the page loading speed.
It is good for desktop mode but it is very bad for mobile mod.

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fel-7l.com%2F&amp%3Btab=mobile&tab=mobile

Please visit above url. Then you can understand me.

I want to know how can I improve the page loading speed on mobile.

Thank you.

Comment: Do other ajax endpoints work?

Comment: Can you click on the console error and tell what the exact error. Please make sure the app debug is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax url you are trying should be either full url.

```
url:'http://localhost:8000/resendotp',
```

OR

route/web.php.

```
Route::get('resendotp', 'EditController@resendotp')->name('resendotp');
```

ajax line:

```
url: {{ route('resendotp') }},
```

Comment: Yes, still bad request.

Comment: Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Check the browser network tab and click on your request. It will show you correct error. Make sure your app debug is set to true if its local env.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to pass `code` parameter to your request :

your ajax function should be like :

```
$.ajax({
url:'/resendotp',
async:false,
data:{id:user_id,phone:phnumber,act1:'sendsms', code:'code here'},  
type:'GET',
success:function(data){  
    alert('OTP sent to '+phnumber);
},error:function(err){
    alert('Error Sending OTP');
});
```

Comment: I can not understand what 'code' means. Could you possibly tell me about it?

Comment: i think @Saurabh Mistry is talking about the post data **code** which should not be the case as he is not even using the same in controller function.